# how to do display none using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="span9">
<span class="disabled">&lt;&lt; previous</span><span class="current numbers">1</span> | 
    <span class="numbers"><a href="/index/page:2">2</a></span> | 
    <span class="numbers"><a href="/index/page:3">3</a></span>
<span class="next"><a href="/index/page:2" rel="next">next &gt;&gt;</a></span>
```

I want to delete '**|**' sign after `span`. I am using **cakephp pagination** . Is it possible to delete thought `css` or `jquery` or `javascript`. Automatically its taking **|** sign from library pagination.

Comment: I don't think it is possible as it is a text node which is in a element with other element children... and since text nodes can't be styled you might not be able to have a pure css fix, though you could use javascript to remove that node...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all the unwraped elements like this,

```
$('.span9').html($('.span9').children());
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/20/)

Answer (score 2):

i think this is the easiest way to replace your | in span text hopefully you may use this

```
 $(".span9").html($(".span9").html().split('|').join(""));
```

[try this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1okznby/2/)

Comment: This would be the approach i would take.. simply copying your div contents back with out the pipes..

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution where the `|` is replaced with  is what you are looking for, then

```
$('span.numbers').each(function(){
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if(next && next.nodeType==3 && next.nodeValue.trim()=='|'){
        next.nodeValue = ' ';
        //or this.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rnyqn9z2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set font-size to 0 of the div and add font-sizes to spans.

```
div { font-size: 0px}
div span { font-size: 14px;padding: 3px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9dog0vk/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the span9 and make the other spans visible.

```
.span9 {
visibility: hidden;
}

.span9 span {
visibility: visible;
}
```